# Trying to use EntityFieldQuery to find all nodes with a node reference field not set

Tags: entities

After some searching the closest code snippet I've found is:

```
->fieldCondition('field_name_ref', 'nid', 'NULL', '!=');
```

This will find everything where the node reference is not null. But if I change the `!=` to `=` it returns nothing. I've tried all the combinations of values I can think of:

- Passing in `NULL` instead of `'NULL'`.
- Passing in `array()`
- Trying `1, "<"`
- `"", "CONTAINS"`
- `"", "="`
- `0, "="`

Plus a few more, just trying all the combinations I can think of.

How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As crazy as it might sound, you can't. Normally you'd use the `IS NULL` operator to do this but it is apparently not supported by EntityFieldQuery:

[EntityFieldQuery does not support isNull or isNotNull](http://drupal.org/node/1157006)

Also I think the EntityFieldQuery internally uses `INNER JOIN`, rather than `LEFT JOIN` so records that don't have a value in your condition table would be excluded from the query results anyway. The issue has been reported several times:

- [EntityFieldQuery doesn't support query for entities without a value for a specific field](http://drupal.org/node/1236748)
- [EntityFieldQuery doesn't support query for entities without a value for a specific field (duplicate)](http://drupal.org/node/1226622)
- [In field_sql_storage_field_storage_query, any condition on a field's column excludes entities with a NULL value for this column](http://drupal.org/node/1240566)

Comment: I ended up using this: http://drupal.org/node/1226622#comment-6809826
Thanks!

Comment: I think this was your very 1st answer on Drupal.SE ...  +1 now, about 4 years later ... And congratulations for hitting the 100 K rep !!!

Comment: Cheers @Pierre.Vriens, apparently I get a t-shirt ;)

Answer (score 5):

For a workaround I added a custom tag to the query and then I used [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7), see [#1157006 at drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-5465034) for more details.